# Image paths with non-latin characters in them not being ignored by mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, utf-8

Here is my mod_rewrite voodoo:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

If image paths have non-Latin characters in them, they do not display. This happens whether the non-latin characters are in the image name of the directory name. Example URLs to images:

```
http://example.com/Århus/some_image.jpg   # broken image placeholder in browser
http://example.com/beer/øl.jpg            # same
```

I have checked and the path to the image in the  tag is correct. But mod_rewrite is redirecting requests for these images to index.php (Firebug's net panel confirmed this). So it's the RewriteCond that's failing to detect that this is for an actual file.

I have added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to the .htaccess file but this doesn't help. What bugs me is that I don't have this problem when testing with XAMPP locally (on Windows), but I do on my server (Dreamhost hosts it). I can't figure out what the difference between the two is or what else to do, so I turn to your collective wisdom.

Comment: Excellent question, and something I should have thought of - duh! I can't, and I get a 404. The URL the server was trying to find is different:
`http://example.com/Ãrhus/some_image.jpg`
That's the wrong Å (obviously) and I've seen it before when UTF8 characters are not decoded properly.
I don't know what to do with this new information now though.

Comment: I loked at the access logs. I saw this:
`86.30.140.183 - - [18/Apr/2011:10:04:12 -0700] "GET /%C3%85rhus/some_image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 516 "http://example.com/%C3%85rhus/some_image.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I'd suggests :

1. Try to see if the host is configured with UTF-8 (system itself)
2. Verify that the apache files are encoded in UTF-8
3. Is the default Charset set in the global configuration file? May be it can change behaviour.

Keep me updated of what you find.

Comment: I ensured .htaccess is saved as UTF8 and still no luck. It's clear that Apache is not understanding URLs containing UTF8 characters properly. I just tried creating a new file, index.html, in the directory called "Århus". Apache fails to serve that page and gives me the same 404 as before (with the Ã in it). Even if I use the encoded version for the Å (%C3%85) it fails.
I looked in Dreamhost's panel to see any options relating to character sets and saw none. I don't know how to "tell" the server to do everything in UTF8.
Thanks a lot for your help, BTW, M'vy - much appreciated.